# Why can't I use a multi-line builder pattern

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I have started looking into Rust (and Warp) just a few days ago. I can't get into my head the following:

Given the following endpoints

```
    let hi = warp::path("hi");
    let bye = warp::path("bye");
    let howdy = warp::path("howdy");
```

Why is the following ok

```
    let routes = hi.or(bye).or(howdy);
```

But not the following:

```
    let mut routes = hi.or(bye);
    routes = routes.or(howdy);
```

Which throws the compile error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types 
   --> src/lib.rs:64:14
    |
63  |     let mut routes = hi.or(bye);
    |                      -------------------- expected due to this value
64  |     routes = routes.or(howdy);
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `warp::filter::and_then::AndThen`, found struct `warp::filter::or::Or`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or()` wraps in a new type. You can use shadowing:

```rust
let routes = hi.or(bye);
let routes = routes.or(howdy);
```

If you really need them to have the same type (e.g. for usage in a loop), you can use the [`boxed()`](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.boxed) method to create a trait object:

```rust
let mut routes = hi.or(bye).unify().boxed();
routes = routes.or(howdy).unify().boxed();
```

Comment: It works! First time I hear of "shadowing". Will have to read up tonight. Thanks!

Comment: [Variable Shadowing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Basically it is redefining a variable with the same name and (possibly) different type and value (as opposed to assignment, which changes the original variable and cannot change the type).

Comment: Can it be "redefined" in a different scope? How to do `if ..{let routes = routes.or(howdy)}`

Comment: No. If you have both `if` and `else`, and both return the same type, you can do `let routes = if ... { ... } else { ... };`

Comment: Oh, bummer. I was hoping to redefine `routes` a number of times in a loop (add all the different endpoints)

Comment: @JAnton Quite a problem. You can't even use trait objects because `Filter` is not object-safe. Maybe a macro can help? Why do you need a loop?

Comment: I am writing a warp lib to be used in Node to basically replace Express with an exact outside skeleton. So the lib first stores a `Vec` with all the endpoints, then proceeds to add them to the `routes` when it's time to `listen`

Comment: `error: expected opaque type, found enum warp::genric::Either`
this is thrown by `routes.or(howdy).boxed()` thanks for all your help, much appreciated

Comment: @JAnton My mistake. You have to use `.unify()`. Edited the answer.